# How to end function in Python

Tags: python, json

I am fiddling with some code i received from the CSGO reddit to implement a bomb timer using the game state integration that was just released, i have managed to make the code work with a HTTP Post JSON as shown below:

```
import time
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import logging
import cgi
import sys
import json
import signal

PORT = 3000
planted = False

#If we ctrl+C out of python, make sure we close the serial port first
#handler catches and closes it
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    ser.close()
    sys.exit(0)

class ServerHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)


    #SimpleHTTPServer doesn't handle post by default. Hacked up way to do it here
    def do_POST(self):
        length = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])
        jsonString = str(self.rfile.read(length))
        print jsonString
        print "---"
        jsonDict = json.loads(jsonString)
        #From here we have a JSON dict, that has whatever data CS is sending

        #For the timer, all we care about is the the 'round' key 

        if 'round' in jsonDict:
            rounds = jsonDict['round']
            if 'bomb' in rounds:
                if rounds['bomb'] == "planted":
                    planted = True
                    print "Bomb has been planted"

                    #timer code here

                    def main():
                        x = 10
                        for i in range(x + 1):
                            time.sleep(1)
                            print(formatTime(x))
                            x -= 1
                    def formatTime(x):
                        minutes = int(x / 60)
                        seconds_rem = int(x % 60)
                        if (seconds_rem < 10):
                            return(str(minutes) + ":0" + str(seconds_rem))
                        else:
                            return(str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds_rem))
                    main()


                #If bomb has been defused, then send the 'C' message
                if rounds['bomb'] == "defused":
                    planted = False
                    print "bomb has been defused"

                #if the round ends, either bomb exploded or everyone died. 
                #Send the 'C' message to stop timer.
                if 'previously' in jsonDict:
                    if 'round' in jsonDict['previously']:
                        if 'bomb' in jsonDict['previously']['round']:
                            planted = False
                            print "Round ran out"

        #not sure if a response is really required. Send it anyway
        response = bytes("This is the response.") #create response

        self.send_response(200) #create header
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(response)))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response) #send response


Handler = ServerHandler
#On windows, Serial ports are usually COM1-3
#On mac/linux this will be different
#Set up our handler for ctrl+c
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

#Start server
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)


#Run server
httpd.serve_forever()
```

however, this part of the code:

```
def main():
    x = 10
    for i in range(x + 1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(formatTime(x))
        x -= 1
def formatTime(x):
    minutes = int(x / 60)
    seconds_rem = int(x % 60)
    if (seconds_rem < 10):
        return(str(minutes) + ":0" + str(seconds_rem))
    else:
        return(str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds_rem))
main()
```

runs itself twice  as shown in the python shell logs, and it says that the bomb has been planted even though the round as already ended completely, was wondering if anyone has any idea why it would run itself twice.

Comment: As I checked your code with this `{"round":{"bomb":"planted"}}` input as json, it worked fine. Provide the input for error case.